# Is there a way to avoid BigInteger/BigDecimal?

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization, bigdecimal

I need to compute something like this (pseudocode):

```
// a, b, x, y are long, x,y <= 10^12

long i = (a - n)/(x*y)
```

and

```
long j = (b - n)/(x*y) - ceiling
```

Sometimes x*y doesn't fit in long. I would like to avoid BigDecimal/BigInteger usage as it is too costly and not needed anywhere else. Is there  a smart math solution e.g. with two longs or smth like that?

Thank you!

**UPDATE**: Sorry, guys, one more constraint: I also have a variable computed as following (maybe it can be rewritten as well):

```
sum += x*y
```

I need to recalculate it to compare with another variable to stop the cycle.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186144/discussion-on-question-by-dmitry-senkovich-is-there-a-way-to-avoid-biginteger-bi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've noticed that the value I'm comparing the `sum` with is long. So I've solved the problem in the following way:

- I'm calculating `i` like this: (long) (((a - n) / (double) x) / y))
- Here goes `j`: (long) Math.ceil((b - n) / (double) x*y)
- The case above overflows of course. But I prevent overflowing doing the following try-catch before:

  ```
          try {
                  xy = Math.multiplyExact(x, y);
                  ...
          } catch (ArithmeticException ex) {
                  // some handling
                  break;
          }
  ```

This trick made by code work faster enough.

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

You could divide two times

```
y = a / (b * c) 

y1 = a / b

y = y1 / c
```

It's hard to understand how you use this `sum` exactly and how the compared value is calculated but would it be possible to store the result of the comparison instead to avoid large values such as if `result` > 0 then `sum` is larger, if result < 0 then other value is larger,...

Comment: seems to be reasonable but I also need to store the current sum of such `m*w`, sorry, I've updated the question